# 4TB GPT drive is raw

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

Let me give some background first before I get into the issue. A few days ago my PC died and after an hour of troubleshooting I finally confirmed that it was in fact the SSD, so I ordered a new. This came today, I installed Windows 7 on it but when I went to My Computer I noticed that my 4TB has gone missing.

So I opened up disk management and got that popup that says a new disk has been detected, and ultimately asks you to choose between MBR or GPT. I picked GPT and created a new volume, I'm just aiming for one that's the full size of the drive.

This did nothing for me, the drive is raw and the only place I can go from here is formatting it, which seems like a very bad idea.

I'm currently using a piece of software called testdisk to attempt to recover the older partition table, but the drive has 486400 cylinders and the 'Quick Search' is really really slow.

What's your take on this?

Comment: If you know what the previous partition was, you can probably try to use gparted to reset it... or use some linux live CD and see if you can access the data. may be best to clone the drive (using CloneZilla or something similar) first so at least you can have some trial run to try a few method of getting it read.

Answer (score 1):

First, creating a new partition table on the disk was the wrong thing to do, at least if you had data on the disk; depending on what tool you used, you may have overwritten critical filesystem data, which means you may need to resort to recovering files one by one with a tool like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). (I hear there are Windows-specific tools that do a better job than PhotoRec for Windows, but I don't recall their names or have URLs handy.)

Second, I suspect that your problem ultimately boils down to a driver with a 32-bit sector limitation. Such drivers are common on Windows, especially 32-bit versions of Windows. (I've heard of some 64-bit installations with this problem, too, but they're relatively rare.) Assuming a 512-byte sector size, a 32-bit sector counter tops out at 2TiB, so disks larger than that will be misinterpreted in one way or another if a driver has a 32-bit sector-count limit. Typically, it works something like a car's odometer topping out; the count starts again at 0 after some point. If I'm right, the size of the disk shown by a partitioning tool will be *way* off -- under 2TiB. If this is the symptom you see, you need to track down the offending driver and swap it out with a fixed one. Sometimes switching the mode in the firmware from "IDE" or "SATA" to "AHCI" will force such a change in Windows -- but reversing such a change can be difficult. Incidentally, "cylinder" values are meaningless on modern disks. (Modern spinning disks *do* have cylinders, but they don't match the "cylinder" values used in some partitioning tools.) The cylinder/head/sector (CHS) system tops out at about 8GB anyhow, so these figures are useless on any but tiny disks anyhow. The [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) system used on bigger disks and on EFI-booted computers doesn't even store CHS values; it uses raw 64-bit sector pointers exclusively.